# How can I save the command and its execution output to file at the same time

Tags: shell

Suppose I have a command `java -cp src/ nlp.lm.BigramModel wsj/ 0.1`, I want to save the command itself and the command execution output to the file at the same time.

One way to do this is to

```
echo "$ java -cp src/ nlp.lm.BigramModel atis/ 0.1" > trace/bigram-trace.txt    
java -cp src/ nlp.lm.BigramModel atis/ 0.1 >> trace/bigram-trace.txt
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

```
( exec >logfile 2>&1; set -x; somecommand )
```

or just

```
( set -x; somecommand ) >logfile 2>&1
```

This would turn on tracing in the `(...)` subshell and redirect all output to the file `logfile`.

If `somecommand` is `mount`, then the file `logfile` may end up looking like

```
+ mount
/dev/sd0a on / type ffs (local)
/dev/sd0d on /tmp type ffs (local, nodev, nosuid, softdep)
/dev/sd0e on /var type ffs (local, nodev, nosuid)
/dev/sd0f on /usr type ffs (local, nodev)
/dev/sd0g on /usr/local type ffs (local, nodev, wxallowed)
/dev/sd0h on /home type ffs (local, nodev, nosuid, wxallowed, softdep)
/dev/sd0j on /backup type ffs (local, nodev, nosuid)
/dev/sd0k on /extra type ffs (local, nodev, nosuid, wxallowed, softdep)
mfs:92196 on /tmp_mfs type mfs (asynchronous, local, nodev, nosuid, wxallowed, size=8388608 512-blocks)
```

The `+␣` (a plus sign and a space) in front of the command is the tracing prompt, or quaternary prompt, which may be changed by setting `PS4` to a prompt string:

```
( PS4='$ '; set -x; df /tmp ) >logfile 2>&1
```

The above may produce something like

```
$ df /tmp
Filesystem  512-blocks      Used     Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/sd0d     10315164       160   9799248     0%    /tmp
```

in `logfile`.

This works well for simple commands, which may be all you need.  For compound commands, the other answers that uses `script` or similar utilities may be a better fit as the shell trace of compound commands do not appear as one may have typed them.  Also variables etc. will be expanded in the trace output.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
echo date | script -q bigram-trace.txt
```

Result:

```
$ cat bigram-trace.txt
date
sh-4.4$ date
Sun, Feb 18, 2018  6:22:13 PM
sh-4.4$ exit
```

Or without a pipe:

```
script -q bigram-trace.txt <<'eof'
date
eof
```

Answer (score 1):

A method that is simple and convenient, particularly if you want to save not just one command but several, is to first run the command `script`, then run your commands.  `script` saves both the input and the output to every command.  When you are done, type `exit` or ctrl-D to exit `script`.

For example, to record both input and output for two commands:

```
$ script
Script started, file is typescript
$ date
Sun Feb 18 16:59:45 PST 2018
$ for i in {1..3}; do echo $((i**2)); done
1
4
9
$ exit
Script done, file is typescript
```

To see the saved information, `cat` the file `typescript`:

```
$ cat typescript
Script started on Sun 18 Feb 2018 04:59:37 PM PST
$ date
Sun Feb 18 16:59:45 PST 2018
$ for i in {1..3}; do echo $((i**2)); done
1
4
9
$ exit

Script done on Sun 18 Feb 2018 05:00:13 PM PST
```

`script` has many options.  See `man script` for details.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a script for something I do often.

```
cat > foo
#! /bin/bash
echo "\$ $1" > "$2"
$1 >> "$2"
^D
chmod +x foo
```

and then run

```
./foo "java -cp src/ nlp.lm.BigramModel atis/ 0.1" "trace/bigram-trace.txt"
```