# Write command used and its output to a file

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have a simple problem that is getting hidden underneath answers to an even more simpler problem.

Let's say I use the command `ls > file.txt` which redirects the `stdout` of `ls` into `file.txt`. The contents of the file.txt might look like

```
some_file.txt
some_dir/
```

What should I do if I also want to capture the ACTUAL command I used. For example, with this new command, the contents of the file should look like

```
$ls
some_file.txt
some_dir/
```

Notice the `$ls` command on the first line. `$` is the bash symbol which is not necessary to solve my problem.

I have a long bash file that takes in user arguments which are then used in bash commands, so printing the complete bash command is a requirement.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain your use case. What's the purpose of creating such a file? Do you have specific requirements for the line that shows the command? Would the shell's output when `set -x` is active be sufficient? Example: `( set -x ; ls ) &> file.txt`

Comment: What does `$` represent? Is it the value of your primary prompt, `$PS1`? Because it clearly wasn't part of the command that you used. What about commands that contain variables, command substitutions or process substitutions? Should they contain the unexpanded command line, or the expanded command? Is that also the case for compound commands like `{ echo hello; echo world; } >file`?  Should no redirection whatsoever be visible in the output file, or should only the redirection to the specific file be removed from the stored text?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I save the command and its execution output to file at the same time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/425039)

Comment: @Kusalananda edited. I need to look closer at your question before i answer it in detail. I am still a beginner to bash scripting.

Comment: @Bodo, thanks for telling me about set -x. I think this will do the trick.

Comment: I suggest to show a short example of a script that uses user input for commands and the (approximate) expected output. You still did not clarify for what purpose you need the output files. You could also do something like `echo command "$user_arg" > file.txt ; command "$user_arg" > file.txt` Do you want error messages to appear in the file or not?

Comment: re. that edit, so are you saying you want to see _all_ commands executed by a script (presumably with no to minor modifications to the script)? And not just one command? If so, why didn't you say that in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: 'Probably not'. You're asking the shell to eat it's own tail. The `>` is just redirecting content. It only knows about output, not the command that the content came from. Your command also isn't written to `history` until it's executed. You could turn on debugging (`set -x`), but that'll also print out term colors/chars which probably isn't what you want. So, best bet might be to just run an extra command after your pipe:

`$ sed -i 1i\\"$(history -1 | cut -f 1 -d ';' | cut -c 8-)"  some_file.txt`

There's probably a more clever way of doing this, but that *should* put your last command into the first line of `some_file.txt`.  Won't work with every command, special chars and all, so you might have to tweak it, but you could also put it in an alias to help simplify it.