# Redirect command options to a file

Tags: nc

From the following nc command,i would like to redirect `source-server.fqdn` name to the output file. By default nc command is not returning the `source-server.fqdn` in the output.

```
nc -zv -s source-server.fqdn dest-server.fqdn 1234 >> file.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: What stops you from using `echo source-server.fqdn >file.txt` before running your `nc` command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I save the command and its execution output to file at the same time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425039/how-can-i-save-the-command-and-its-execution-output-to-file-at-the-same-time)

Comment: @Kusalananda Or something like `{ echo source-server.fqdn; nc -zv -s ...; } >>file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

`nc` command does not provide the source server's fully qualified domain name (FQDN) in its output.`-s` option in `nc` is used to specify the source IP address, not  FQDN.

if you want to include the source server's FQDN in the output, you would need to use a different command. for example, you could use `nslookup` to get the FQDN of the source server and then use `echo` to include it in the output. Here's an example:

```bash
echo "Source server FQDN: $(nslookup source-server-ip | grep name | awk '{print $4}')" | tee -a file.txt
nc -zv -s source-server-ip dest-server.fqdn 1234 >> file.txt 2>&1
```

here, `nslookup source-server-ip | grep name | awk '{print $4}'` is used to get the FQDN of the source server. `tee -a file.txt` command is used to append the output to the file.